# Why does Eclipse 2018-12 asks the question whether to create a module or not?

Tags: java, eclipse

When the project name is entered and the Create button pressed, Eclipse issues a dialogue box that has the title "Create module-info.java" and an input box named Module Name with the project name already entered as its content. The message from the dialogue box says "Discouraged module name. By convention, module names usually, start with a lower case letter". Why does Eclipse 2018-12 ask this question?. Is it a must to create a module?. I clicked the "Don't Create" button

Comment: It's for the module system introduced in Java 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Module is a new feature of Java introduced in Java 9, derived from [Project Jigsaw](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/), proposed from [JSR-376](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=376).

While it is not necessary to create a module, it is a recommended way for modularity. Eclipse 2018-12 has the latest Java support, which requires it to support this feature, shows by asking whether you need to create a module when you create a project.